# How to drop rows in pandas, following more than one criteria?

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, drop

I would like to drop the rows which have "No Change" or "New" in the columns "Change Type".
What is the best way to do it? I cannot figure out how to use booleans or "|"

`df3_capacity_issues= df3new.drop(df3new.loc[df3new['Change Type'] == "No Change"| "New"].index, inplace=False)`

Why does not this work?

Thank you

Comment: The syntax in the conditions is wrong. Try this: `df3new.loc[(df3new['Change Type'] == "No Change") | (df3new['Change Type'] == "New")]`  You should post sample data for further help.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way. Assume that your df is

```
 id Change Type
0    1   No Change
1    2   No Change
2    3   No Change
3    4   No Change
4    5        New 
5    6        New 
6    7        New 
7    8        New 
8    9      Others
9   10      Others
10  11      Others
11  12      Others
```

Then, define a list of what you want to drop and then keep only the rows that do not contain these:

```
listdrop = ['No Change', 'New']
df3_capacity_issues = df3new[~df3new['Change Type'].isin(listdrop)]
```

which returns

```
 id Change Type
8    9      Others
9   10      Others
10  11      Others
11  12      Others
```